# Добавление и воспроизведение музыки из listbox при помощи winmm.dll

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть lisbox и 3 кнопки: воспроизведение, стоп, пауза.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при загрузке программы из указанной папки были добавлены в listbox музыка и при выборе пользователем воспроизводилась.
Загружать получается, но не всех форматов так как получается указать только один формат в фильтре. В списке есть, но воспроизводить не воспроизводит.
Код программы:

```
    string[] Playlist = new string[1000];
    int count;
    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //загрузка музыки

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"Media\Music");
        FileInfo[] mus = dir.GetFiles("*.mp3");
        for (int i = 0; i < mus.LongLength; i++)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items.Contains(mus.GetValue(i)) == false)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(mus.GetValue(i));
                    Playlist[count] = mus.GetValue(i).ToString();
                    count += 1;
                }

            }
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex < 0)
            { listBox1.SetSelected(0, true); }
    }
    private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string d = Playlist[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
        Player.open(d);
        Player.play();
    }

    private void Pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player.pause();
    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player.stop();
    }
```

Воспроизведение, стоп и пауза прописаны в отдельном классе:

```
    public void play()
    {
        string command = "play MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public void pause()
    {
        string command = "pause MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
    public void stop()
    {
        string command = "stop MyMp3";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Скажите как все реализовать правильно?

Comment: Ваш вопрос надо бы разделить на два. Первый - получение файлов с несколькими фильтрами. Второй - проблемы с воспроизведением.

Comment: Исправил. Второй просто как-то дополнительно было.

Comment: Вы метод `open` не привели. Возможно, в нём alias неправильно задан. Или `DllImport` неверно сделан. У меня пример с кодпрожекта работает.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на первую часть вопроса.

```
// Поле класса. Ну нужно изначально задавать массиву размер,
// потому что файлов может оказаться больше.
string[] playList;
```

```
// Код в Form_Load.
playList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(".")
    .Where(file => file.EndsWith(".mp3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        || file.EndsWith(".wav", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .ToArray();

listBox.DataSource = playList;
```

---

Ответ на вторую часть вопроса.

Где только вы откопали эту библиотеку? Как я понимаю, имеется в виду winmm.dll?
Вот [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16316/Audio-Player-using-winmm-dll-and-WPL-File) подробное описание её использования.

Упрощённый класс с двумя методами:

```
class Player
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand,
        StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, int bla);

    public void Open(string file)
    {
        string command = "open \"" + file + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }
    public void Play()
    {
        string command = "play MediaFile";
        mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Прежде чем начать воспроизведение, медиа-файл нужно открыть.
Вызываем так:

```
var player = new Player();

player.Open(playList[0]);
player.Play();
```

Comment: Ой прошу прощения. Ошибку допустил я как раз им и пользовался.