# Проигрывание файлов с помощью winmm.dll

Tags: c#, winapi, dll

Собственно, задача следующая, используя winmm.dll воспроизвести файл.

```
         [DllImport("winmm.dll")]

    private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, 
    StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr oCallback);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strFileName = @"C:\Users..";
        string PlayCommand = @"open " + strFileName + "alias MediaFile";

        mciSendString(PlayCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);



        PlayCommand = "play MediaFile";

        mciSendString(PlayCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Реакции - 0.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457618/184217

Comment: Там на формах, вполне возможно что там оно работает. Мне же в консоли нужно..

Comment: Попробуйте атрибут `[STAThread]`. Но возможно, не сработает если вы будете блокировать ваш поток. Попробуйте, работает ли это в UI-приложении для начала.

Comment: без изменений. на формах тоже не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без атрибута `[STAThread]` действительно не работает. С ним - всё отлично!

Ещё нужны кавычки вокруг названия файла.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = "The Starry Sky.mp3";

    string command = "open \"" + file + "\" alias MediaFile";
    mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

    command = "play MediaFile";
    mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Ууупс. Судя по всему я атрибут ставил перед импортом библиотеки. Так да, действительно работает. Спасибо