# Как воспроизводить файлы с помощью winmm.dll в C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, аудио

Пытаюсь воспроизвести файл .mp3 по прямой ссылке из интернета. Вот метод, который использую:

```
public void Play(bool url = false)
{
    string command = String.Format(@"open ""{0}"" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile",
        (!url ? (directory + "\\" + filename) : (this.url)));
    mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    command = "play MediaFile";
    mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Дело в том, что воспроизводятся не все файлы. Например трек по ссылке:
https://cs9-2v4.userapi.com/p8/890573dd1e9341.mp3
работает нормально.

А по ссылке:
https://cs9-6v4.userapi.com/p8/728cc80e9ff446.mp3
не воспроизводится.

Программа просто продолжает работу, но звука нет. Почему такая избирательность? Как воспроизводить файлы по всем ссылкам?
P.S. пробовал воспроизводить эти файлы с компьютера `(url == false)`, опять же файл скачанный с первой ссылки имеет звук, а с второй звука нет. Значит дело в самом файле. Хотя в Aimp этот файл отлично запускается.

Comment: В меня ваши ссылки не работают

Comment: @Zergatul, это ссылки с серверов вк, может вы из Украины и поэтому у вас не работает.

Comment: Через оперу зашел, мне пишет 404.

Comment: @Zergatul, так вы откуда сами? У меня все открывается в браузере

Comment: Я с Украины, поэтому захожу через оперу с впн.

Comment: Суть в том, что у меня все ссылки работают в браузере, а в проекте не все. Почему так?

Comment: Может потому что ссылки работают только с залогинеными пользователями? Учитываются куки, другими словами

Comment: Я кстати тоже так подумал, поэтому стер кукисы и перешел по ссылке. Все равно все окей.

Comment: Может на сервере стоит проверка на `User-Agent`

Comment: Зачем вк запрещать просмотр клиентам с оперы.

Comment: Кажись они просто привязывают доступ к ип. Я вытащил эту ссылку со своего ип, вот и сам могу смотреть на любых браузерах и без кукисов, а с другого ип эта ссылка не грузится. НО проблема кардинально не в этом!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/457613/184217

Answer (score 0):

В итоге посоветовали вот такую либу: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx
В ней все воспроизводится как надо.

Пример простого кода:

```
private WindowsMediaPlayer WMP;
public void Play(string filename)
{
    WMP = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
    WMP.URL = filename;//Указываем путь
    WMP.controls.play();//Запускаем
    WMP.settings.volume = 100;//Можем изменить громкость
}

public void Stop()
{
    WMP.controls.stop();//Останавливаем воспроизведение
    WMP.close();
}
```

Comment: А можете добавить ещё и примерный код для пользы будущих читателей?